# How can I use effects like `.show('slow')`

Tags: javascript

How can I use `.append()` with effects like `.show('slow')`

Having effects on append doesn't seem to work at all, and it give the same result as normal show(). No transitions, no animations.

```js
$(function () {


    var html = "<div id='str'>Hello</div>";

    $('#btn').click(function () {
        $('#cont').append(html);
    });
    
    
    
});
```

```html
<button id='btn'>click</button>
<div id='cont'></div>



<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
$(function () {
$('#str').hide();

    var html = "";

    $('#btn').click(function () {
        $('#str').toggle(1000);
    });
    
    
    
});
```

```html
<button id='btn'>click</button>
<div id='cont'></div>

<div style="display:none" id='str'>Hello</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you really are desperate about the adding HTML

```js
$(function () {
$('#str').hide();

    var html = "";

    $('#btn').click(function () {
    $('str').innerHTML ="Hello"
    $('#str').toggle(1000);
    if($('str').style.display=="none"){
    $('str').innerHTML =""
    }
    });
    
    
    
});
```

```html
<button id='btn'>click</button>
<div id='cont'></div>

<div style="display:none" id='str'></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I need to add the html code every time I click the button

Comment: Why? That seems very illogical. With display:none, it is as if it is not there.

Comment: Actually, I'm using it to add the same form to my site.

Comment: If you want, I can show you what I'm talking about so you can understand what I mean

Comment: I edited it; use the second one

Comment: a lot of errors

Comment: Your code has so many error like `=` is incorrect

Comment: sorry, I fixed it

Comment: Sorry, but the same error